# How to convert a string of a binary number into a binary number?

Tags: python, type-conversion

```
x = '0b001'
```

I need `x` to be `0b001` so that is a binary number, I tried doing `int('0b001')` however the 'b' gives an error due to being a character.

How to convert `'0b001'` into a binary?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a decimal value of binary string, you can use `int()` with `base` argument set to `2`.

```
x = '0b001'
decimal_x = int(x, 2)
```

```
decimal_x = 1
```

If you want to remove the '0b' from the binary string, do a string slice as below

```
x = '0b001'
x = x[2:]
```

```
x = '001'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the base number to `0`:

```
>>> int('0b001', 0)
1
>>>
```